# How to prevent html 5 page to prevent storing cache is browser?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, metadata

I want to avoid storing cache is user browser

I am using html5 is there any alternative for html4 meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

what i have tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
...............
```

i have create a **manifest.appcache** file like this

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Cache manifest version 1.0

# no cache

NETWORK:
*
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't solve same problem, but mine was in Edge.

But maybe it can work in IE, so give you what I got.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" />
```

I hope this code helps you. :)